# Crashed if using NSMutableArray to accept json

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I create a NSMutableArray and initial it in `viewDidLoad`

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *arrayDATA;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _arrayDATA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

And I request a json by using AFNetworking from the server, the json format like this

```
{
 "code": 0,
 "statu": "success",
 "datalist": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "ADPL"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "GOOG"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "LIKE"
  }
 ]
}
```

And I give the response data to arrayDATA like this

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"username":username, @"password":password};
[manager POST:URL parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    [self setArrayDATA:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]]; // works fine
    [_arrayDATA addObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]]; // will crash
    [self.tableview reloadData];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
}];
```

As the code comment say

If I use `[self setArrayDB:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];` the function works well, but if I use `[_arrayDB addObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];`, the function will crash, what's the correct way to use addObject here?

The crash info

```
  [__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000001a940
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000001a940'
```

Comment: Crash? What's the error message? I think it's in your tableView datasouce, not that line that causes the crash. It should be `[_arrayDB addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]]`. Do not use `setArrayDB:` because you already alloc/init it in viewDidLoad:.

Comment: what is the crash report

Comment: @Larme Sorry, my mistake, I have updated it, and add crash info.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Please look append info.

Comment: Remove `[self setArrayDATA:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];`, and just do `[_arrayDATA addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];`. Just may want to do a `[_arrayData removeAllObjects];` just before if needed.

Comment: @Larme No, I only use one, as I said, if I use `[self setArrayDATA:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];` it works fine, if I use `[_arrayDATA addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];` it will crash, I don't use them at the same time.

Comment: Why is `arrayData` set as `copy`? Also, these lines shouldn't create a crash. None of these lines should create the crash `[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector`. Could you track which line is causing the crash?

Comment: This question is solved, `[_arrayDATA addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];` is the right answer.

Comment: @FahimParkar Can you vote my answer? So everyone meet this question can see it, thanks.

Comment: @yeleko : better if you post an answer with explanation, which I already did. would be great if you accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is an error and arrayDATA and arrayDB are the same.

But the crash is because you are setting the element "datalist" of the responseObject to arrayDB. Then arrayDB is a NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. So you cannot add more elements.

On the other hand, you don't need to init the mutable array in viewDidLoad if latter you are going to set a new pointer to a new object.

Try to change the setArrayDB: line with this:

```
self.arrayDB = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];
```

Comment: @yeleko The reasons are the same. `[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]` is a `NSArray`, so when you do `[self setArrayDATA:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];` you replace your `NSMutableArray` by a `NSArray` object, so just after doing `[_arrayDATA addObject:` crashes.

Comment: @yeleko Do what I say in the answer. That's all.

Comment: @Gabriel thank you, but the right answer that I give under my question, still thanks a lot.

Comment: @yeleko both of them are right. Both solve the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all return type of `[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]` is Array and not NSDictionary.

***Point 1***

```
[self setArrayDATA:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]]; // works fine
```

This is fine because you are setting array for an array.

***Point 2***

This will crash because you are adding array as `addObject`.

```
[_arrayDATA addObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];
```

You should use as below to make it working

```
[_arrayDATA addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Point1: "This is fine because you are setting array for an array." No, setting a `NSArray` for a `NSMutableArray` and overriding the previous init. After `[self setArrayDATA:[responseObject objectForKey:@"datalist"]];`, `_arrayDATA` is a `NSArray` and not a `NSMutableArray`.